# Как использовать ::ng-deep только в одном компоненте?

Tags: css, angular5

Вопрос такой:

Достался на доработку проект на Angular 5. Хочу использовать `::ng-deep` в CSS только в 1 компоненте, при этом добавляя код в CSS компонента, стили применяются ко всему проекту.

Comment: Привет. Я немного не понял вопроса. Если ты хочешь **НЕ** выходить за пределы компонента попробуй использовать в стилях обертку в виде **:host**, если же наоборот, то надо убрать ViewEncapsulation (В декораторе компонента поставить `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`)

Comment: Обёртка :host не помогает в этом, вот этот кусочек ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane{ left: 300px !important;  }, я везде находил что данный обёртка работает только для данного компонента, но в данном случае обёртка ::ng-deep применяется для всего приложения

Comment: А компонент не рутовый ? То есть на каком уровне иерархии он находится??

Comment: А что ты подразумеваешь, под рутовый?

Comment: Не на первом, 2  или 3

Comment: Надо код глянуть, так трудно понять